# how to get html data from site

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, axios

`<noscript><strong>Javascript is enabled in your web browser on a specific site while implementing web crawling. If you disable JavaScript, this text will change.</strong></noscript>`

I checked that the same tag was added. For a site that includes this tag, even if you request to get the site url with axios, the html value does not come in completely. How can I solve this? (I used Google Translate. Sorry.)

https://vibe.naver.com/chart/total <= this site

Comment: If you need web crawling for a site with JavaScript executed, you need something like https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/

Comment: Translated via Google Translate, the site's `<noscript>` tags reads: `"The screen cannot be displayed because JavaScript is disabled. Please enable JavaScript in your browser settings and try again"`. This is normal SPA (single page application) behavior, where React/Vue/Angular/Svelete (Vue in this case, based off of the source code js) tells a client that JavaScript needs to be enabled to see the content of the page because JavaScript makes the text appear. You'd need something like puppeteer mentioned above if you want to webcrawl

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what problem you have, but this code should work

```js
       const axios = require('axios');
       axios.get("https://vibe.naver.com/chart/total").then(html => {
        console.log(html.data)
})
```

Method using node-fetch

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
fetch("https://vibe.naver.com/chart/total").then(result => result.text()).then(result => {
console.log(result)
})
```

If you aren't getting the entire site, it could be anti-bot measures

Comment: It's due to the website using a Single-Page-Application framework (Vue), which requires JavaScript to use properly since the JS controls the text displayed. Just fetching the raw HTML wouldn't do anything, you'd need to use something like pupeteer

Answer (score -2):

I'm not very sure what programming language you are using, or if you are even using one.

But you won't be able to get any backend source from Naver; you will only see the front end html codes with bunch of links to the backend source codes.

**This is a small amount I got from inspecting HTML:** (Its all a single line)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="ko"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="description" content="좋아하는 음악은 물론, 좋아할 음악까지 들려주는 취향 저격 뮤직 서비스"><meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=1338631589"><meta property="og:type" content="website"><meta property="og:image" content="https://music-phinf.pstatic.net/20201019_118/16031004163365Jexk_JPEG/about.jpg"><meta property="og:title" content="NAVER VIBE(바이브)"><meta property="og:description" content="#나만을 위한 음악이 듣고 싶을 땐 #내돈내듣 VIBE."><meta property="og:url" content="https://vibe.naver.com"><meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"><meta name="twitter:image" content="https://music-phinf.pstatic.net/20201019_118/16031004163365Jexk_JPEG/about.jpg"><meta name="twitter:title" content="NAVER VIBE(바이브)"><meta name="twitter:site" content="NAVER VIBE(바이브)"><meta name="twitter:creator" content="VIBE"><meta name="twitter:description" content="#나만을 위한 음악이 듣고 싶을 땐 #내돈내듣 VIBE."><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/icon/icon_120x120.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/images/icon/icon_120x120.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/images/icon/icon_152x152.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" href="/images/icon/icon_167x167.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/images/icon/icon_180x180.png"><title>VIBE (바이브)</title><link href="/20210611235311_resources/css/common.314db81d.css" rel="prefetch"><link href="/20210611235311_resources/js/common.435f4ddf.js" rel="prefetch"><link href="/20210611235311_resources/css/app.f381a573.css" rel="preload" as="style"><link href="/20210611235311_resources/css/chunk-vendors.598bb52f.css" rel="preload" as="style"><link href="/20210611235311_resources/js/app.54f33238.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/20210611235311_resources/js/chunk-vendors.b833ef5d.js" rel="preload" as="script"><link href="/20210611235311_resources/css/chunk-vendors.598bb52f.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="/20210611235311_resources/css/app.f381a573.css" rel="stylesheet"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js?attr=6Lte6dwVvrAUmIXAmrO3pKxbbcRLcOyA1czuw93D8LByqZTbj1qR4t2QiZ9_JGMjj_RlN8QK-X9i0K0eVweFfA" charset="UTF-8"></script><link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/E3E8934C-235A-4B0E-825A-35A08381A191/abn/main.css?attr=aHR0cHM6Ly92aWJlLm5hdmVyLmNvbS9jaGFydC90b3RhbA"/></head><body><noscript><strong>자바스크립트가 비활성화 되어있어 화면을 표시할 수 없습니다. 브라우저 설정에서 자바스크립트를 활성화 후 다시 시도해 주세요.</strong></noscript><div id="app" class="app"></div><script src="/20210611235311_resources/js/chunk-vendors.b833ef5d.js"></script><script src="/20210611235311_resources/js/app.54f33238.js"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: i'm using nodejs.. 
Then, is it not possible to import the html data of https://vibe.naver.com/chart/total with axios?

Comment: That is a programming language I am unfamiliar with, sorry.